# Background image fitting the webpage without scrolling

Tags: html, css, background

I am making a website, that have a background image. The problem is that the background image have the scroll to go down to the page and i dont know why.

I tried everything, and nothing works. Nothing seems to remove the scroll. I only want the backgrounf image to fit the page. I placed height: 100% and nothing!

[image: background]

The image is supose to fit the user page, but the scroll is there to go down the page.

html:

```
<mat-toolbar style="background-color: black; color: white; top: 0; width: 100%" >

  <button mat-raised-button routerLink="/profile" class="buttons"> About me</button>

  <h1 style="margin: auto;">LoL Not Alone</h1>

  <button mat-raised-button onclick="window.location.href='https://paypal.me/FabioHeitor?locale.x=en_US';"> Donate </button>

</mat-toolbar>


<body>
</body>
```

css:

```
body{

  /*margin-top: 62px;*/
width: 100%;
  height: 100%;


  /*margin: 0;*/
  min-height: 100%;

  /*background-size: cover;*/
  /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  /*background-position: center center;*/

  background-image:url("../../../assets/Images/home.png");
  /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
  /*background-size: 100% 100%;*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
  /*background-position: center;*/
  /*background-size: 100% 100%;*/
  /*background-size: cover;*/

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;



}
```

What is commented is what i have tried and nothing seems to work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed Background Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550568/fixed-background-image)

Comment: no, bacause i dont want to scroll

Comment: That’s what a fixed background means :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
html, body {overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of 100% use 100vh. It will use view height as reference, instead of a percentage.

Comment: Did that and the image gets smaller, but like 50% smaller

Comment: when you use vh the proportions stay the same, so play around with the numbers, you can also use vw which uses the width.